# PHP alter array with same date to array with unique date and total count

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array shown as following:

```
array
(
  [0] => array("date"=>'2016-01-01',"type"=>1),
  [1] => array("date"=>'2016-01-13',"type"=>1),
  [2] => array("date"=>'2016-01-03',"type"=>1),
  [3] => array("date"=>'2016-01-01',"type"=>1)
  ....
)
```

I would like to sort them by unique date and total amount according to the date:

```
array
(
  [0] => array("date"=>'2016-01-01',"type"=>1,"total"=>2),
  [1] => array("date"=>'2016-01-03',"type"=>1,"total"=>1),
  [2] => array("date"=>'2016-01-13',"type"=>1,"total"=>1)
  ....
)
```

Are there any PHP build in array function can do this?
Or i should create my own function?

Comment: Is this array values generated from database

Comment: show the sql query

Comment: @Devs I know i can use SELECT DISTINCT(date) as date COUNT(date) as total FROM table GROUP BY date... but i cannot modify the SQL, so i plan to use PHP array function to do it manually

Comment: you no need to modify SQL. use the sql query in PHP to retrieve

Comment: @Devs Sorry devs, i means the query :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is certainly no single function that does this magically, this would be solved by multiple functions.

First, you'll need to group up the array using the `date` as you key, putting it inside a new container

```
"date"=>'2016-01-01' // group it by this value
```

So in order to do this, you'll need to assign new values using those as your index.

Second, to prepare your array to be sortable, just convert those `date` keys that will be used into unix timestamp `strtotime`. So that it'll be easier to sort out later.

So all in all it would look like this:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $v) {
    $date_key = strtotime($v['date']); // turn into unix time
    if(!isset($new_array[$date_key])) { // initialization
        // turn total to zero first
        $new_array[$date_key] = array_merge($v, array('total' => 0));
    }
    $new_array[$date_key]['total']++; // increment
}
```

After array values are gathered, then, you'd want them sorted using `ksort`

```
ksort($new_array); // sort by date
$new_array = array_values($new_array); // remove unix time keys
```

[Sample Output](https://3v4l.org/u7fLg)

Answer (score 0):

Group By the date field and use COUNT for the total rows

```
$sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(date_field) as total 
FROM table 
GROUP BY date_field";
$qry = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($qry) > 0)
{
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_object($qry))
{
// Date Array
}
}
```

Comment: I cannot made changes to SQL... as i mentioned before

Comment: there is no modification in SQL. This is just a query used to retrieve data. Then how will you retrieve the data?

Comment: The reason i cannot change my SQL query is to guarantee the performance of retrieving speed, cause the table is quite big and is crossing with others, i cannot use INNER JOIN and have to carefully while selecting fields to prevent additional resource wasted...

Answer (score 0):

**For reference only:**

```html
$arr = [
  0 => array("date"=>'2016-01-01',"type"=>1),
  1 => array("date"=>'2016-01-13',"type"=>1),
  2 => array("date"=>'2016-01-03',"type"=>1),
  3 => array("date"=>'2016-01-01',"type"=>1)
];

// count
$date_arr = array_column($arr, 'date');
$times_arr = array_count_values($date_arr);
$date_arr = array_map(function($value){
 global $times_arr;
 $value['total'] = $times_arr[$value['date']];
 return $value;
}, $arr);

// unique
$date_arr = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $date_arr)));

var_dump($date_arr);exit;
```

Answer (score -3):

May be just

```
$array[0]["total"] = 2;
$array[1]["total"] = 1;
$array[2]["total"] = 1;
...
```

Comment: Uhm... how did you get this array?